# Como pasar datos desde una actividad hacia un fragment que está dentro de un view-pager?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewpager

**Descripción:**

Tengo una actividad la cual contiene un view pager  el cual tiene dos fragments dentro. Necesito saber que tengo que hacer para pasar datos desde esta actividad hacia cualquiera de estos dos fragments que están dentro del view pager.

**Código de la actividad:**

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_clases);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    adapter adaptador = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adaptador);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

**Place Holder Fragment Class**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

private model modelo;

public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(index){
        case 1:
            fragment= new fragment1();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment= new fragment2();;
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    modelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(model.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt("section_number");
    }
    modelo.setIndex(index);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contenedor, container, false);

    return root;
}
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.f1,R.string.f2};
private final Context mContext;

public adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un bundle

Comment: El que abre los fragments es el View pager adapter. Cómo paso bundles ahí????

Comment: Por favor , incluye todo el código necesario para que podamos ayudarte. Donde creas los fragments , donde se haga la transicion de un fragmet a otro, etc.

Comment: @Alexmaister actualicé la pregunta con más datos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar un bundle

```
public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(index){
        case 1:
            fragment= new fragment1();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment= new fragment2();;
            break;
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Key", "Aqui pones la informacion que quieres pasar");
    bundle.putInt("Key2", 2);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle); //<-- No olvides esta linea
    return fragment;
}
```

Despues dentro del fragment puedes obtener los datos asi:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("Key");
    int numero = getArguments().getInt("Key2");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```